# Can I access my private bitbucket repository with ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bitbucket

On my site, I'm currently generating a list of tags from one of my repositories hosted on bitbucket.org using jquery. But in order to do this, I had make the repository public. I would prefer to keep it private.

Is it possible for to me to allow the site access to my respository in this way, while still keeping the repository private.

The code looks like this (in this form, it will produce a list in the console of the all tags).

```
$.ajax({
        url:"https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jeffreycwitt/publicrepository/tags",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (returndata){
           $.each(returndata, function(key, value){
               console.log(key)
    });
});
```

Comment: You will have to use authentication. You could do it in a server side file to keep your details private.

Comment: I would have to abandon my javascript approach then, yes? I write in php, would I need to access the api through some version of curl and php? Or is there a simpler way? (I think I tried this before and got stuck :( )

Comment: You'd have your JS, just modified so the calls are proxied through your PHP.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining how that would work -- do you think you could offer me an example when you have some time?

Comment: I've never actually worked with the API, so just taking guesses.

Comment: Use AJAX to call whatever authentication script in the background and proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I've learned that an "Authorization header is needed." And the consensus seems to be that this cannot be done with JSONP requests in jquery. I don't really know why.

But I have been able to achieve the desired result by writing a php script that passess the authorization header through a php `file_get_contents` call. Then as suggested by the comments above, I can use the ajax script to load the desire data. The php script looks like this:

```
context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
)
));

// Make the request 
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

//parse data
//turn json data into an array
$obj_a = json_decode($json, true);

//get all keys of array
$tags = array_keys($obj_a);
```

So if anyone wants to retrieve all the tags from a private bitbucket repository, this is how you do it. Bitbucket api documentation doesn't saying anything about how to authentic into a private repository except by means of CURL. But adding the header is what you need to do if you are not using CURL.

Hope that helps someone. (Please feel free to edit this answer if you can think you explain this better).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an [app password](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html) to authenticate, to avoid exposing your account password:

```
const username = 'your-username'; // USERNAME, not email
const appPassword = 'app-pass';
const repoOwner = 'you-or-your-team';
const repository = 'repository-name';

$.ajax({
    url: `https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/${repoOwner}/${repository}/tags`,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(`${username}:${appPassword}`)
    },
    success: console.log,
    error: d => console.log(d.responseText),
});
```